# Tortoise SVN Commit to a new repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Background:

I commit a subversion project to assembla with this folder structure.

```
folder1
folder2
```

But I made a mistake, folder1 should be in folder2. So I did that in my local copy and did a SVN commit. So, now I have folder1 is both the 'base folder' and inside folder2.

```
folder1
folder2
  folder1
```

So, I started reading on how to remove files/folders in SVN and it seems complicated or just scary (what if something goes wrong). I figured I can use a new repo. I can delete the old one since the latest copy, the one I want, is on my local machine. However, here is the issue, when I right-click on the folder, SVN commit automatically points to the existing repo.

How do I change it to point to a new repo. I'm afraid that if I delete the server repo and use the same name, it will complain about mismatch revision/HEAD or something.

Thanks!

Comment: The only scaring part is *removing directories from the repository completely*, as if they never existed, but it does not seem that this is what you want or need; thus Lazy Badger's answer is probably what you should go for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do is use a new repository, and if you have created that new repo, then you can use the [**Relocate** option of TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-relocate.html).

Answer (score 1):

> So, I started reading on how to remove files/folders in SVN and it seems complicated or just scary

Well, **really** it's easy - remove in Working Copy and commit or `svm rm URL/TO/FIOLDER/` in order to delete directly in repository

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the folder and commit the deletions via TortoiseSVN. That's what i'm doing.